# wxWidgets fails to build due to missing wxxml.lib

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, wxwidgets

Apparently anything GUI-related in terms of components involves XML. I cannot go around actually configuring and building wxWidgets from source because of that. I'm new to wxWidgets.

My current setup is on Win10 with MSVC v141 (Visual Studio 2017) with the latest CMake version (currently 3.21).

Inside the `config.cmake` of the wxWidgets projects (using latest `master` branch) I see

```
wx_get_dependencies(EXTRALIBS_XML xml)
```

I am also calling CMake with `-DwxUSE_XML=ON` (among other parameters) but this still leads to:

- the XML dependency is nowhere to be found
- respectively it's not built

Linking then fails with the following error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'wxxml.lib' [C:\Users\...\CMakeBuilds\ef5b5ada-ee42-7735-988a-ae37c735ccff\build\deps\build\wxwidgets\libs\qa\wxqa.vcxproj]
```

What library is actually wxWidgets using and how do I trigger it's retrieval and accordingly configuration and building? Since I am adding wxWidgets to my CMake project as an `ExternalProject` component, I would appreciated something in that line of thought. However any kind of information regarding this issue is more than welcome especially since it will shine light on how to configure other features (if I want them in the future) such as WebView.

Comment: What OS and wx version you are trying to build? What compiler? Are you getting this error trying to build the library or the application?

Comment: @Igor, sorry, forgot to put that. It's been a long day.

Comment: and you didn't answer my last question...

Comment: @Igor "configuring and building wxWidgets from source" - unless we are talking about the demos and samples, I'd say it is clear that I'm talking about the library itself. :)

Comment: @rbaleksandr, did you cloned wxWidgets repository? And if so - did you use the command from the docs or just `git clone...`?

Comment: Also, wxWidgets does not depend on the wxXml - there is only one component that does - XRC library.

Comment: @Igor I did just a `git clone`. The problem with `--recurse-submodules` is that I don't know if it will also initialize the dependencies I have already added as submodules to my main project and I'm building as `ExternalProject` entries.

As for your second comment regarding XML - I'm very new to wxWidgets but from what I understand `XRC` is similar to `QRC`. If I want to build the GUI version of wxWidgets (as stated in my question), it appears that I cannot exclude XRC. If it were a console only version, that's a different story. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: two points. 1. `git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets.git` - this is the way to get the source code of the library and I'm not sure what do you mean by saying `initialize the dependencies`. You will need to build the library anyway - what is the problem?

Comment: 2. You misunderstood. XRC system is the same as resources. Look at the xrc sample. Basically you create something like rc file for MSVC and then load you windows, icons and everything from XRC, instead of creating the code. Some people prefer it that way. Other than that wxWidgets itself does not depend on the XML. And of course you still can build the GUI - it will just be a C++ code, instead of some resource file which you will load (XRC way).

Comment: The definition of `--recurse-submodules` is automatically initializes and updates all submodules. If (and it seems so) libpng, zlib etc. are such submodules, I will get those. This defeats the `sys` option for those dependencies if I still need to use the ones provided as submodules of wxWidgets. Last but not least I will get two versions of the same dependencies.

Comment: Also, you don't need the extra `expat` library - especially on Windows. wxWidgets will provide it for you. Now, I do hope that you already created your application and it is ready to be shipped to the customers. Otherwise I wouldn't bother with `CMake-thingy` and build the wxWidgets and everything normal way and finish the development.

Comment: no you will not. You are not building with `configure` option and you are not using *nix/Mac. The `sys` option was created just for that - if you want to use system provided libraries, and also I believe it is the default on those OS I mentioned. But on Windows selecting it will do nothing - Windows doesn't have a notion of system libraries, especially when building with MSVC.

Comment: and yes all those mentioned libraries are now submodules for wxWidgets and you should use the official, documented way of getting the source code.You should get rid of this extra `expat` library, unless your project depends on the XML functionality. wxWidgets certainly doesn't. And besides - you can always use wxWidgets library in your project.

Comment: I am moving to wxWidgets from Win32 API in order to also be able to use Linux systems. Using `sys` option is there for a reason. Unless it's broken it allows the user to use own versions of the given libraries. `builtin` is the one that requires the submodules to be retrieved. In my case building the libs separately should be viewed as the libs being already present on the system and wxWidgets simply using those and not building them. I do not want to be connected to wxWidgets in case I decide to switch to a different GUI, which may happen depending on my experience with wx.

Comment: you are missing the point. the `sys` and `builtin` options make sense when used by the configure script - whether in *nix/Mac or when building by Cygwin. When you are building with MSVC you will build everything. When you build with MinGW - you can turn off the USE_XRC and USE_XML options. There are no other for that compiler. NOw when you build your software - you can decide what library to link with in the linker options. MSVC doesn't have a notion of using `sys` or `builtin` - it works with whatever is passed to the solution/makefile.

Comment: When you will move to *nix, you will have a `configure` script where you will be able to provide those options and not to build that library and so not link it to the final product at all. But not on MSVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wxxml.lib` issue is fixed now. While fixing it I also discovered a bug (of sort) in the build system of wxWidgets.

The reason why it failed to build this library in particular was actually quite simple but due to the lack of knowledge in the dependencies of wxWidgets. I thought that wxWidgets, given it depends on XML so much, has its own XML parser. Well, not really. The `wxXML` component actually uses and underlying 3rd party dependency called **EXPAT**, which - as you can see in my question - I have deactivated since it was giving me issues during the build (due to the still present problem of not being able to automatically retrieve dependencies).

What I did was to clone the [`libexpat` repository](https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat), add it as an `ExternalProject`, set the variables for the libraries and include directory and pass them onto my wxWidgets project. But there is a catch...

The `expat.cmake` file looks as follows:

```
#############################################################################
# Name:        build/cmake/lib/expat.cmake
# Purpose:     Use external or internal expat lib
# Author:      Tobias Taschner
# Created:     2016-09-21
# Copyright:   (c) 2016 wxWidgets development team
# Licence:     wxWindows licence
#############################################################################

if(wxUSE_EXPAT STREQUAL "builtin")
    # TODO: implement building expat via its CMake file, using
    # add_subdirectory or ExternalProject_Add
    wx_add_builtin_library(wxexpat
        src/expat/expat/lib/xmlparse.c
        src/expat/expat/lib/xmlrole.c
        src/expat/expat/lib/xmltok.c
    )
    set(EXPAT_LIBRARIES wxexpat)
    set(EXPAT_INCLUDE_DIRS ${wxSOURCE_DIR}/src/expat/expat/lib)
elseif(wxUSE_EXPAT)
    find_package(EXPAT REQUIRED)
endif()
```

I would use the `*.cmake` files of the 3rd party dependencies stored inside `<ROOT_OF_WXWIDGETS_PROJECT>/build/cmake/lib` to determine which variables I need to set if `builtin` is selected as the value for the respective library. Since I want to use my own I need `sys` (e.g. `-DwxUSE_EXPAT=sys` as a `CMAKE_ARGS` inside my wxWidgets `ExternalProject`) and also to pass the headers and libraries accordingly.

Given the file above one would assume that `EXPAT_LIBRARIES` is required. However after failing to build (yet again) and seeing that the reason was the activated expat build and that it was set as `builtin` I checked the log in detail and found the following error:

> Could NOT find EXPAT (missing: EXPAT_LIBRARY) (found version "2.2.6")

Notice the `EXPAT_LIBRARY`. After passing it (`-DEXPAT_LIBRARY=...`) my build was complete. For me this is a bug or simply inconsistency between the dependency `cmake` file and the rest of the wxWidgets project.

It is important to note that I do not retrieve the external dependency through wxWidgets itself (see `config.cmake` and more precisely the macro `wx_get_dependencies(...)`). This solves the problem with a basic configuration and build of wxWidgets but if you don't want to tackle every dependency of wxWidgets on your own (why should you?), I recommend looking for a solution where the dependencies (at least the ones you don't want to deal with) are automatically retrieved, configured and build as `builtin`.